# Checking char array value with specific format

Tags: c++, validation, char

This partial code check for specific format in char array.

```
char emp_id[10];

    cout<<"Employee ID\t\t: ";

    while(cin.getline(emp_id,10)) {
        if (emp_id[0] == 'e' || emp_id[0] == 'E'){
            break;
        }
        std::cout << "Input error. Invalid employee ID format." << std::endl;
        cout<<"\nEmployee ID\t\t: ";
    }
```

The accepted format is `e<employee ID number>`. For example: `e3` or `E59`. Any letter after `e` are not accepted such as `Eg`, `e56h`, `e77$` etc. etc.

I manage to check whether the first letter in array is `e` or `E` with the above code. Then I didn't know how to check for invalid format such as `Eg` or `e56h`. If this question had been asked before please point me to the answer page because I'm not sure what search keyword should I use. Please help me and thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Try using substring after first char and converting into int as below:

```
   int myNum = atoi(emp_id.substr(1, emp_id.length()).c_str());
```

If successful then good otherwise fail it.